# Connecting to SQL host trouble

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm new to using PHP and mySQL and basically I'm getting this error when I try to run my Website.

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): Unknown MySQL server host 'host' (1) in /**/**/**/**/**/register.php on line 2 Unknown MySQL server host 'host' (1)
```

here is the line 2 code i'm using in my register.php file

```
mysql_connect('host', 'database', 'password') or die (mysql_error());
```

I have 3 files create-table.php, index.php and register.php. The tutorial I was following said "but don`t forget to change the host, database and the password to yours" Which I don't understand how to do. 
Here is my create-table code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect('host', 'database', 'password') or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('database') or die (mysql_error());
mysql_query("create table users(
username varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
password varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (username)
)") or die (mysql_error());
//Show "Complete" if everything works
echo "Complete.";
?>
```

Comment: You should use mysqli or PDO... avoid mysql since its not supported anymore...

Comment: it should be `username` not `database` in second parameter, and check your host name, it might be `localhost`

Comment: The examples you found online are using placeholders so they can later be modified to fit your needs. This would include your `host`, `database` and `password` to your MySQL server you are attempting to connect to.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have a record in yours hosts file to point 'hosts' to 127.0.0.1 or 'localhost', then you need to use 'localhost' for your hostname.

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'database', 'password') or die (mysql_error());
```

Assuming (of course) that your mysql socket is locally hosted.

See the documentation on [`mysql_connect`](http://php.net/mysql_connect) for many examples of how to connect to mysql.

Also, side note... Mysql is on it's way to deprecation. If this is new code, consider [`PDO MySQL`](http://php.net/PDO) instead.

Comment: When changing it to localhost I receive the error "Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'database'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /**/**/**/**/**/register.php on line 2 Access denied for user 'database'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" Had a quick look through the page you linked but I can't really find anything to solve this

Comment: Also, I have no idea why it's saying password: YES

Comment: Just for the record I'm following http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/Simple-PHP-Login-script/62679

Comment: @user182 You need to put in the mysql username and the corresponding password where it says 'database' and 'password' for your script. 'database' is the location of the username and 'password' is the user's password. We cannot tell you what this is, as only you know what it could be. Defaults are typically User: root, password: mysql, or User: root, Password `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Your connection `mysql_connect();` shoud contain username of your database instead of database name

```
mysql_connect('host', 'username', 'password') or die (mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

u have to give ur host, user, and password. i usually use:

```
   define('MYSQL_HOST',"localhost");
    define('MYSQL_USER',"youruser");
    define('MYSQL_PASS',"youpassword");
```

and after that i connect to database and select it:

```
$db->Connect("localhost","youruser","yourpassword");
    $db->selectDb("databasename");
```

Comment: Why tell him to define the data, and don't use the define afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

```
$host = "localhost";
$username = "myusername"; //replace myusername with your real mysql connection username
$password = "mypassword"; //replace mypassword with your real mysql connection password
mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die (mysql_error());
```